# Django Reverse Query OFFSET 1

Tags: python, sql, django, reverse, offset

I'm having an issue with the OFFSET while reversing the query. I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.
**The following two lines of code *do not* OFFSET the reversed query by 1.** However both will OFFSET anything greater than 1.

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:2:1]
Article.objects.all().order_by('id').reverse()[:2:1]
```

The second number in the square brackets is the OFFSET, the first is the LIMIT. If I was to put a 2 in the OFFSET the query offsets by two, however when I put a 1 in the OFFSET the query offsets by 0. **How can I OFFSET by 1?** Is there a bug in the django framework?

Comment: I was thinking maybe copying the query lines in a list, and then accessing the lines as elements from the list, however it would be kind of annyoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood slice syntax. It is exactly the same as with a list. It is the *first* parameter that is the start, but you have omitted that parameter completely; you have only supplied the second (end) and third (step) values.

Your code should be:

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('-id')[1:2]
```

or just

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('-id')[1]
```

Comment: Your first line does not reverse, I want DESC ORDER. Yours skips oldest then newer and then the newest. I want newest to older. The Second line is throwing me an error 'Article' object is not iterable'

Comment: Yes it does, it uses order_by -id. You can use `reverse()` instead but it does exactly the same thing. The second one returns a single article rather than a queryset; since you only wanted one anyway I'm not sure why you want to iterate.

Comment: If I have 3 database entries 1 2 and 3. 1 being the oldest and 3 the newest. Your first line returns 2 and 3. I want it to return 2 and 1.

Comment: Really, no it doesn't. It returns a single object, which is the second-newest one. In any case, you shouldn't be relying on ids for ordering; if you want to order by creation time, you should add a timestamp to the model.

Comment: Your first line is working now with 1:3. There must have been cache in the browser. 1:3 returns 2 and 1. Thanks man!

Comment: I do have a timestamp. Is using timestamps for ordering best practice?

Comment: Yes; ids are not guaranteed to be in creation order, although they *probably* will be.